# How to hide files in SharePoint People Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages

I am building a new SharePoint intranet for my company. I need to include a directory and wanted to use the people web part. But I can't let everyone see the files people have been working on - this is highly confidential information. I just want to display basic contact information, a photo, an associated org chart, and possibly a short description.

Any thoughts on how to do this? I am stumped!

Answer (score 0):

People web part in SharePoint online only shows the recent files you've shared in OneDrive for work or school, SharePoint Online, or Outlook on the web with *the person looking at your profile*.

Only you can see your private documents on your own profile card unless you have shared them with others.

Other users can only see documents on the profile card to which they already have access in Office 365. Have a look at [Your profile in Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/profile-cards-in-microsoft-365-e80f931f-5fc4-4a59-ba6e-c1e35a85b501) to learn more about what is shown on the profile card.

Currently there is no out of the box way to customize the SharePoint default people web part and even if you are able to hide it from people web part by using any workaround or disabling use of Microsoft graph API in your tenant (which is not recommended), other users will still have access to the documents which they have permissions to. They will still be able to open them, search for them in SharePoint/OneDrive search.

If you want to keep a document private and do not want to show it on your profile cards, store it in OneDrive for Business and choose not to share it with anyone. If you want you can always share it with others later.

Read more about it at: [New Profile Cards show recent files - although we have the graph disabled](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/new-profile-cards-show-recent-files-although-we-have-the-graph/m-p/90406)

---

If you want custom functionality as per your company requirements, you will have to develop it on your own using [SharePoint framework (SPFx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Check below custom SPFx web parts which will help you to get started with:

1. [Microsoft Graph People Search](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-msgraph-peoplesearch)
2. [People Directory](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-people-directory)

All custom web part samples are available at: [SharePoint FrameWork client-side web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)